# How to change format of this type of date "/Date(1496117136317)/" in AngularJS?

Tags: date, datetime, angularjs-scope, date-parsing

Get date from controller like this **/Date(1496117136317)/** in Ajax response and its datatype is **datetime**.

How can I convert its format?

Answer (score 0):

It's a `UNIXTIMESTAMP`. You can get a Date object like this:

```
var date = new Date(1496117136317*1000);
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();
```

If you have this `/Date(1496117136317)/`,

```
var str = "/Date(1496117136317)/";
var res = str.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/","");
```

and then

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(res)*1000);
```